# UITableView partial loading

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

hi I have an `UITableView`. It loads numberof data from a web service. What I want to load this tableview 10 by 10.Initially it loads first 10 items. When user scroll to the end of the `UITableView` it should load next 10 of records from the server.  so in my `scrollviewDidEndDeclarating` delegate I put like this

`

```
 if (scrollView.tag==24) {


    [self performSelector:@selector(loadingalbumsongs:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}`
```

but the problem is when I stop the scroll it is getting stuck untill load the table view. Can anybody give me a solution for this

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're not loading the data asynchronously.

Comment: because your webservice is not asynchronous.. so it just wait until the next 10 records come

Comment: what can I do to stop this stucking screen

Comment: You need to call reload function after storing the data from webservice.
in reload function,
You need to fetch data from DB, and update sourceArray of the tableView and call [self.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

Try NSURLCONNECTION that will help you to call asynchronous webservice

A NSURLConnection object is used to perform the execution of a web service using HTTP.
When using NSURLConnection, requests are made in asynchronous form. This mean that you don't wait the end of the request to continue,

This delegate must have to implement the following methods  :

```
connection:didReceiveResponse : called after the connection is made successfully and before receiving any data. Can be called more than one time in case of redirection.
connection:didReceiveData : called for each bloc of data.
connectionDidFinishLoading : called only one time upon the completion of the request, if no error.
connection:didFailWithError : called on error.
```

**EXAMPLE: -**

```
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSURL *url_string = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     @"Your URL"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url_string];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                  delegate:self];
    if (!conn) {
        // this is better if you @throw an exception here
        NSLog(@"error while starting the connection");
        [data release];
    }
```

for each block of raw data received you can append your data here in this method :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)someData {
    [data appendData:someData];
}
```

`connectionDidFinishLoading` will call at the end of successfully data receivied

Answer (score 0):

use this code for load more action

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height indicates UItableView scrool end
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        if(loadMore)
        {
            loadmore=no;
            //call your Web service
        }
    }
}
```